# Error performing search to fill vector

Tags: c#

I'm having a return error when making a search to fill the vector `PegaTipo[]`, the error is:

> "System.NullReferenceException" : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object".

The class is `Pegatipo[]` the return vector:

```
    public PegaTipo[] buscaFunc(string func, int ID_empresa)
    {
        SqlDataReader objReader;
        SqlCommand objcmd = null;
        PegaTipo[] retornaInfo = null;
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        int t;

        vsql = "SELECT [NOME], [CPFCNPJ], [HIDE] FROM CLIENTE WHERE TIPO = @TIPO and ID_EMPRESA = @ID_EMPRESA";

        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {

                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);

                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TIPO", func));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_EMPRESA", ID_empresa));

                objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (objReader.Read())
                {
                    arr.Add(objReader.GetString(0));
                    arr.Add(objReader.GetString(1));
                    arr.Add(objReader.GetBoolean(2));
                }

                t = arr.Count / 3;

                int j = 1;

                retornaInfo = new PegaTipo[t];


                for (int i = 0; i < t; i++, j++)
                {
                    retornaInfo[i].nome = Convert.ToString(arr[0 * j]);
                    retornaInfo[i].tipo = Convert.ToString(arr[1 * j]);
                    retornaInfo[i].hide = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[2 * j]);
                }

                return retornaInfo;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }
        }

        return retornaInfo;
    }
```

Serialization:

```
   [DataContract]
   public class PegaTipo
   {
      [DataMember]
      public string tipo { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public string 
      [Dnome { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public bool hide { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the array of PegaTipo, but you are not creating instances of PegaTipo inside the array so the sentence:

> retornaInfo[i].nome = Convert.ToString(arr[0 * j]);

is throwing your exception because retornaInfo[i] is null. You should do this inside your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++, j++)
{
    retornaInfo[i] = new PegaTipo();
    retornaInfo[i].nome = Convert.ToString(arr[0 * j]);
    retornaInfo[i].tipo = Convert.ToString(arr[1 * j]);
    retornaInfo[i].hide = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[2 * j]);
}
```